# How to suspend a process that has registered a keyboard/mouse hook with SetWindowsHookEx In windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I need to suspend a remote process from time to time, but the problem is that the existence of the mouse/keyboard SetWindowsHookEx hooks is causing the system to lag a lot because i assume windows is waiting for that process to response to the mouse/keyboard event.

What is the best solution for this problem if i have to suspend a remote 64 bit process from my 32 bit procsess if it has a keyboard and mouse hooks?

I thought maybe i should remove the hook before suspending but couldn't find any info on how to do so?

Comment: for what need suspend process ?

Comment: @RbMm I need to lock the process if i detect some anomalies and scan it. But i 100% need to lock that process, and i assume suspending it is the only way.

Comment: You cannot implement security from the outside in. Whatever you are trying to accomplish, the solution you decided on won't get you there.

Comment: @IInspectable unfortunately i have no say in that, i just have to solve this problem.

Comment: Not the target 64bit application, but rather your 32bit hook application. *"the 32-bit hook is injected into each 32-bit process (the usual security boundaries apply). In a 64-bit process, the threads are still marked as "hooked." However, because a 32-bit application must run the hook code, the system executes the hook in the hooking app's context; specifically, on the thread that called SetWindowsHookEx. This means that the hooking application must continue to pump messages or it might block the normal functioning of the 64-bit processes."*

Comment: In other words if you're going to hook cross bitness [you need to handle what that entails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) according to the docs. Because it looks like the hooking application must pump messages always if there is any cross bitness. However MS recommends making separate hooking apps for each bitness.

Comment: @Mgetz Sorry i didn't get what you mean by "Not the target 64bit application, but rather your 32bit hook application". My 32 bit app is NOT using SetWindowsHookEx, that remote 64 bit is, and when i suspend it, it freezes the computer. So what is the solution you are saying?

Comment: @OneAndOnly the way I read your question you have a 32bit hooking app (for universal hooking) and a 64bit target. That said if you read the documentation the result doesn't change. Because cross bitness hooks are run in the context of the hooking application, not the target. If you stop pumping window messages in the hooking app it will cause issues. e.g. it isn't suspending the target the could be causing the issues, it's failing to pump messages in the hook.

Comment: @Mgetz So how can i resolve this issue from my 32 bit app? What exactly i need to do or what APIs i need to call before i suspend the remote process (the one that has registered hooks) ?

Comment: @OneAndOnly AH ok you're suspending the hooking app.. you need that app to disconnect its hooks first or you'll cause the issues described. If needs be you can do create remote thread and load code into that app to potentially unhook but I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Without access to the `HHOOK` handle that the remote process has registered, you can't just inject code to unhook it. And even if you could, you don't know the function(s) the process is using for its hook callbacks, so you can't re-register them after resuming the process.